# Is there any possibility to use socket.io just for specific part of application?

Tags: node.js, express, ionic-framework, mongoose, socket.io

I am pretty new in socket.io. Just I want to know is there any possibility to use socket for certain part of application and the rest continue working with normal http RESTful API?

To be more specific, I have develop an app with ionic 5 for frontend and nodejs, express and mongodb for backend.

I have added socket.io into my app.js file same as below and server is listening.

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
console.log('a user connected')
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    io.emit('user-changed', {user:socket.username,event:'left'});
})
socket.on('comment',(comment)=>{
    console.log(comment)
    io.emit('comment',{cmt: comment.text,user:socket.username, createdAt: new Date()})
})})
```

My route file for discussion APIs

```
const express = require("express");
const router = require("express-promise-router")();
const discussionController = require("../controllers/discussion.controller");
const auth = require("../../helpers/auth");

router.route("/").get(discussionController.getAllDiscussions);
router.route("/discussion/:id").get(discussionController.getDiscussion);
router.route("/comment").post(auth, discussionController.createComment);
router.route("/comments/:id").get(auth, discussionController.getComments);
router.route("/search/:params").get(auth, discussionController.searchDiscussion);
router.route("/create-discussion").post(auth,discussionController.createDiscussion);

module.exports = router;
```

My controller file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Discussion = require("../../models/discussion.model");
const Comment = require("../../models/comment.model");

module.exports = {
  getAllDiscussions: async (req, res, next) => {},
  getDiscussion: async (req, res, next) => {},
  getComments: async (req, res, next) => {},
  createDiscussion: async (req, res, next) => {},
  createComment: async (req, res, next) => {},
  searchDiscussion: async (req, res, next) => { }
};
```

Also in my app.module n front, I have added SocketIoModule and Config same as below.

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:5000', options: {} };
```

So, everything is working fine and I can send and receive comment from discussion page too.
What I want is the possibility of opening socket just for discussion page not enitre app and also how can I integrated with my server side controller to save into database and retrieve it.

Comment: Well i'm not familiar with Ionic, but you can initiate the socket anywhere in your frontend application, in any component. It doesn't have to come from some high level module/component.

Comment: @i.brod Yes that's true. I have changed it from app module to discussion module and solved my issue but  how about the server side. How can I implement it in y controller instead of my app file?

Comment: So problem solved?

Comment: @i.brod not yet actually. server side stillI have problem to use socket for saving and retrieving data.